# How do I prevent IntelliJ from importing classes used in JavaDocs when I call optimize imports?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is importing classes declared with `{@link ...}` inside JavaDoc when I call "Optimize imports ..." on my project.

How do I prevent that behaviour?

Answer (score 7):

Go to *Settings/Editor/Code Style/Java/Imports* and select *If not already imported* for the *Use fully qualified names in JavaDoc* option.

That way fully qualified names should be preferred for links to classes in JavaDoc which are not already imported in the current file.

Answer (score 2):

[image: please see screenshot below]

As a hack, increase the number against `class count to use import with '*'  and Names count to use static import with '*'` to a high value as below screenshot